# Simple non-recursive formula for inverse permutation to A316385

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, oeis

Let
$$
\ell(n)=\left\lfloor\log_2 n\right\rfloor
$$
Let
$$
f(n)=n+2^{\ell(n)+1}
$$
Let $a(n)$ be [A316385](https://oeis.org/A316385), i.e. lexicographically earliest sequence of distinct positive terms such that for any $n > 0$, $a(n) \operatorname{AND} a(2n) = a(n)$ (where $\operatorname{AND}$ denotes the binary $\operatorname{AND}$ operator). Here
$$
a(2n+1) = n + 2^{\ell(n)}, \\
a(2n) = f(a(n)), \\
a(1)=1
$$
Let $b(n)$ be [A316472](https://oeis.org/A316472), i.e. Inverse permutation to [A316385](https://oeis.org/A316385). Unfortunately, the page in OEIS does not contain any useful information.

Let $T(n,k)$ be the $(k+1)$-th bit from the right side in the in the binary representation of $n$.
$$
T(n,k)=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^k}\right\rfloor\operatorname{mod}2
$$
Let $g(n)$ be [A059893](https://oeis.org/A059893), i.e. reverse the order of all but the most significant bit in binary expansion of $n$. Here
$$
g(n)=2^{\ell(n)}+\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\ell(n)-1}T(n,k)2^{\ell(n)-i-1}
$$
Let $h(n)$ be [A153152](https://oeis.org/A153152), i.e.
$$
h(2^k-1)=2^{k-1}, \\
h(n) = n+1, \\
h(1) = 1
$$
Let $p(n)$ be [A153142](https://oeis.org/A153142), i.e.
$$
p(n)=g(h(g(n)))
$$
Let
$$
q(n)=p(n)-2^{\ell(n)}
$$
Let
$$
r(n)=(2q(n)+1)2^{\ell(n)-\ell(q(n))-1}
$$
Here we consider that $\ell(0)=-1$.

I conjecture that $$r(n)=b(n).$$

Here is the PARI/GP prog to check it numerically:

```
l(n) = logint(n, 2)
f(n) = n + 2^(l(n)+1)
a(n) = if(n == 1, 1, my(A=n\2); if(n%2, A + 2^l(A), f(a(A))))
g(n) = my(L = l(n)); 2^L + sum(i=0, L-1, bittest(n, i)*2^(L - i - 1))
h(n) = if(n == 1, n, if(l(n+1) == valuation(n+1,2), (n+1)/2, n+1))
r(n) = my(A = 2^l(n), B = g(h(g(n))) - A); (2*B + 1)*A/2^(if(B>0, l(B), -1) + 1)
test(n) = a(r(n)) == n
```

Is there a way to prove it?